# Print bar inside bar with mathplotlib python

Tags: python, charts, bar-chart, sample

I'm trying to make a bar chart using python mathplotlib.
My chart must be this:

[image]

But I can't draw the bar that contains the sub-bars.
Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I tried to draw the main bars over the subbars, but they move the whole pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example, which plots bars inside bars:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y1 = [1, 2]
x1 = [1, 3]

y2 = [0.5, 0.7, 0.6, 0.9]
x2 = [0.7, 1.3, 2.7, 3.3]

plt.bar(x1, y1, width=1.5)
plt.bar(x2, y2, width=0.5)
```

I don't think, that this is your actual problem. What precisely do you need?